# how to Implement lit-element-bootstrap package in lit-lement

Tags: javascript, html, css, lit-element, lit-html

I would like to implement `lit-element-bootstrap` package in lit-element.

I am getting following error in console,
`Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec`

```
//header.js
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js?module';
import  'https://unpkg.com/lit-element-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.10/lit-element-bootstrap';

export class Header extends LitElement{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render(){
        return html`
        <bs-alert primary>
         <div>A simple primary alert—check it out!</div>
        </bs-alert>
        `;
    }
}
customElements.define('header-element', Header);


//index.html

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.2.7/webcomponents-bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.2.7/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
     <script type = "module" src = "../components/header.js"></script>
  </head>  
<body>   
<header-element></header-element>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are trying to import from is getting redirected (302).

Current URL: `https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js?module`

Try changing it to:
`https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element@0.7.1/lit-element.js?module`

Not sure if you should be loading it from this URL always, you can download the file and import it from your directory, rather than downloading it from this new URL. As this new URL can also change in future.

Answer (score 0):

lit-element has been updated, the correct link would be `https://unpkg.com/lit-element`
or if you want to specify the extension
`https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js`